# calculate $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \cos(at) e^{-bt^2} dt$

Tags: improper-integrals, integral-transforms

Could someone please help me to calculate the integral of:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \cos (at) e^{-bt^2} dt.$$

a and b both real, b>0.

I have tried integration by parts, but I can't seem to simplify it to anything useful. Essentially, I would like to arrive at something that looks like: 7.4.6 here:
[textbook result](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_302.htm)

Comment: yep! But... I can't seem to simplify it to anything useful. Essentially, I would like to arrive at something that looks like: 7.4.6 here http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_302.htm

Comment: You need to specify the domain.

Comment: Sorry. done now

Answer (score 1):

Do you have restrictions on 'a' and 'b'?

For example, they are real and > 0.

Otherwise, things are messy!

See [here](http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=Cos%5Ba%2ax%5D%2aExp%5B-b+%2a+x%5E2%5D&random=false) for details.

Comment: a and b are both real; and b>0.

Hmm.. I should have written this question up a bit better. I apologise.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:*

Use the fact that
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{iat- bt^2}\,dt = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{b}} e^{-a^2/4b} $$
which is valid for $b>0$.

To derive this formula, complete the square in the exponent and then shift the integration contour a bit.

Comment: Hey @fabian , what does it mean to 'shift the integration contour'? I am not familiar with such a thing/method?

Comment: Thanks! I think I see what you mean now.

Comment: I think it must be $\,a^2/4b\,$ in the exponent of the exponential, because of that $\,i\,$ there...

Comment: @DonAntonio: I checked again. I believe it is correct. Note that $i a t - b t^2 = -a^2/4b -b(t-ia/2b)^2$.

Comment: You're right, of course. I oversaw that minus sign before the quadratic term. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, you overlooked that minus sign.