# Calculate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cos(a t) e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}dt$ using $E[U_t]$ where $U_t = cos(\sigma W_t)$ where $W_t$ is Brownian Motion

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Related: [calculate $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \cos(at) e^{-bt^2} dt$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191125/calculate-int-infty-infty-cosat-e-bt2-dt)

> Consider the Brownian Motion $U_t = \cos(\sigma W_t)$, where $W_t$ is a given Brownian Motion. Find $dU_t$ and then $\mathbb{E}[U_t]$. Hence, calcuate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cos(a t) e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}dt.$

Using Ito's formula, I've found:

$$E[e^{\frac12\sigma^2t}U_t] = E[X_t] = X_0=1.$$

or

$$E[U_t] = e^{-\frac12\sigma^2t}.$$

(more details here: [Using Ito Calculus to find $\mathbb{E}[U_t]$ if $U_t= \cos(\sigma W_t)$ where $W_t$ is Brownian Motion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3506613/using-ito-calculus-to-find-mathbbeu-t-if-u-t-cos-sigma-w-t-where-w/3506651#3506651))

From this, I'm a bit cautious on making the jump to solve the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cos(a t) e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}dt$? How would you do it?

Comment: The answer is the link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191125/calculate-int-infty-infty-cosat-e-bt2-dt (your own link). Why don't you just take $b=\frac12$?

Comment: @JohnB What about using the result I've already derived? The question says, find $E[U_t]$ and hence calculate the integral.

Comment: Then please change the title of your question and state exactly what is your problem.

Comment: @JohnB Done - not sure it is clearer

Comment: Write the expectation of $U_t$ as an integral with respect to the density of $W_t$: $E[\cos(W_t)]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty {1\over \sqrt{2\pi t}}\exp(-x^2/2t)\cos(\sigma x)\,ds$.